# Laravel Routes not working when using vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

im using vue js with laravel and i want my SPA to start from the home page and i want normal login to home page. when i access the login route from welcome page, it works fine and gives me the login form, [like in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htp9y.jpg)

how ever when i want to access my app through xampp localhost my login route doesnt work and gives me a 404 error.[like in the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG0Lf.jpg)

i would really appreciate if someone can help me

Comment: one more thing, if i enter login page without using the login button on the welcome page and just write login on my url in my browser "localhost/Laravel/todo/public/login". it works.

Comment: Do you want to run the project from the root path like localhost/laravel ?

Comment: @SachinKumar yes i have my laravel projects inside a folder laravel which is a folder in htdocs. one of these projects is todo which i want to run. runs fine with php artisan serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the Laravel project from the root folder instead of the artisan serve command

**Option 1.**

Rename the "server.php" file in the root directory, to "index.php"
Move your .htaccess from public folder to root directory

**Option 2.**

you can also make the .htaccess file on the root of the project folder with the following content

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```